# VSCode checkJs automic typedef and enum discovery

Tags: javascript, enums, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Is it possible for VS Code to automatically discover typedefs and enums in my code base?

For example, let's say we have the following structure:

```
/
└───constants
|   |    enums.js
|
└───typedefs
|   |    some_def.js
|
└───some/other/deeply/nested/folder
|   |    a_file.js
```

In enums.js I have something like:

```
/**
 * @enum
 * @global
 * @readonly
 */
export const MY_ENUM = {};
```

I can't seem to reference this enum anywhere else unless I do something like this:

```
@param {import('/constants/enums.js').MY_ENUM} This is so verbose :(
```

The same problem occurs if I want to reference a typedef from `some/other/deeply/nested/folder`

Even with the `@global` annotations, it doesn't seem to make a difference. Is there an easy way around this or does it all need to be manual?

EDIT:

Here is my jsconfig file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "checkJs": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your project have a [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson)? If not, try creating a basic one to see if that helps. It should make VS Code treat all js files in your workspace as part of the same project

Comment: @MattBierner thank you for the suggestion. I in fact do have a jsconfig file already. I will add some details of it to the question, though.